# How do I get a transparent background in Illustrator CC?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, background

I need help trying to make a transparent background. I do realize that the transparency is there, but I have enabled "Show transparent background" and there is still a white background behind my image. I know this sounds noobish, but this is my first time with Illustrator, I don't usually do work with it, I had to for this one time.
Here's something I made to upload here to show as an example of what I mean.
[image]
**EDIT:**Since I had some comments that require answers, and I just registered so I dont have enough rep to reply, this is how I'm going to do it. 
The image was a raster image, brought it over to Illustrator and traced it already, what you see in the image is a vector image (traced).
Until now, I used the pen tool and selected the surrounding, selected the whole image and created a clipping mask, that got rid of most of the white background, however, because of my bad use of the pen tool, it leaves an outline on the shape, so I still have trouble with it.

Comment: Hi Sam, is that a raster image with a white background (jpg, gif or png etc) you've placed in your file? If so, your best option is to trace that shape, which as it's simple, 1 colour and symmetrical, should be pretty easy or to use you can use Illustrators "Image Trace" function.

Comment: Hi Sam, welcome to GDSE! It would appear you have accidentally created multiple accounts. Stack Exchange only allows one account per user on a site.  Please go to our [help section](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) and contact SE to have this issue fixed.

Comment: Re: your edit: you might want to try and `Object > Expand Appearance` the trace to be able to edit the shapes in the trace. You could also try and change the Trace settings and check `ignore white`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Used the Magic Wand tool and selected the white space background, then pressed the delete button on my keyboard and done.
It is a bit weird because I tried that before and it didn't work, I don't know how it worked this time.
**FINAL ANSWER:** A comment on the post, moderator Vincent, provided the answer. On my real project it also removed some white parts of the content as well, but I can put those back. Thank you, Vincent. 
P.S.: I submitted the form for accidental multiple accounts.

Comment: HI msamprz, the user is talking about the program Adobe Illustrator which does not have a magic wand tool.

Comment: Hi Andrew, thank you for your response. I am OP, and yes, I am using Adobe Illustrator, it's Illustrator CC 2015, and I am very well sure it is a Magic Wand tool :)
However, when I attempted it again on my real project and not the example above, it is no longer working, so I'm confused now.

Comment: So you have two user accounts now, msamprz?

Comment: @SamF Oh you're right, I am mistaking. I haven't used that tool since it was added.

Comment: @Johannes I did, until twenty minutes ago, but Vincent, helped me out and now I only have one.